# extract boolean value from boolean expression with regex and java

Tags: java, regex, boolean-expression

I have a boolean expression like the following:

```
A && B || C
```

I need to extract `A`,`B` and `C` values from the expression.

As operands I need to consider only `&&` and `||`, parentesis are not considered.

Is there a regex to do this?

Comment: I'd not do this via regexp, simple replace/split will work better, like `str.replace("&&", " ").replace("||", " ").split(" ");`

Comment: Why not just search all matches of `\w+`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
\w+(?= (?:&&|\|\|))|(?<=(?:&&|\|\|) )\w+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC0sC4/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\w+                # match 1 or more word characters
(?= (?:&&|\|\|))   # lookahead to assert next position is space and && or ||
|                  # regex alternation
(?<=(?:&&|\|\|) )  # lookbehind to assert previous position is && or || and space
\w+                # match 1 or more word characters
```